# Delete folder/album from Photos

Tags: photos.app

How do I delete a folder or an album from Photos?  Have searched internet for answer and tried using control, option and command keys.

Answer (score 0):

- Right-click on the folder/album and select Delete.
- Select the folder/album and press ⌘⌫